# fill_parent in LinearLayout isn't being honored

Tags: android, android-layout

After much research on both SO and google, I haven't seen any one with exactly the same problem I am experiencing, so here it is:

I recently redid the entire UI on an android app. For the most part, I made only cosmetic changes to each of the screens. They appear in the UI editor of eclipse perfectly as expected. However, directly after doing this, two of the screens stopped being laid out correctly on both all tested devices and the emulator.

Now, the big problem one these two screens was that the root level LinearLayout didn't appear to be actually honoring the fill_parent for either layout_height or layout_width. it looks like it's being measured as if it were set to wrap_content instead. It only takes up about 70% of the screen - which is just enough to wrap the individual elements inside the root LinearLayout. I would post an image, but as a new user, I am not allowed to.

The layout isn't stretching to fill the screen. Here's the code for layout, except that there are a few more in the LinearLayouts containing a TextView and an EditText.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    style="@style/sans.white.16.bold"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:text="@string/edit_account" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUTextView
    style="@style/sans.white.14"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/first_name" />

<com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUEditText
    android:id="@+id/acc_editor_first"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I think the root LinearLayout should be filling both height and width. I've used this same layout many MANY times in our app without problems. (A quick count revealed that I used 76 LinearLayouts in our app, and all but two of them are working.)

At first, I suspected that perhaps our custom classes measure was wrecking things, so I changed the layout to use all plain EditTexts, but there was no change. I double checked the activity, but it isn't doing anything except to load this xml. So, in desperation, I redid the layout like so:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/sans.white.16.bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:text="@string/edit_account" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

After that, The words Edit Account appear with a black background mashed into the upper left corner. Clearly, the LinearLayout isn't filling the parent.

Long story short, I am asking how to fix this so that the LinearLayout fills the screen as expected.

I am at a complete loss as to why this is happening, and I am certainly hoping that someone on SO has an idea. This has got me pulling my hair out!

Comment: I've seen this problem when using layout weights.  My solution was to force the length of the layout to 0, and then everything magically worked.  There's definitely a bug in Android somewhere

Comment: Gabe, I'm not quite sure I get what you are saying. Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting fixed width and height for the root layout.
Then only you will be able to debug who is driving length and width. It is very much possible that parent activity or background activity is setting dimensions. Once you identify the root cause you can go back to original settings.

As of now from your code snippet given here, nothing wrong here

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did that. I gave it a minWidth and minHeight, and it worked as expected... But the moment it ran on a tablet, it looked awful.

I considered that it might be the activity initially, but no where in the activities code is it changing or even utilizing anything related to measure.

Comment: Another thing: I just discovered that wrapping the entire thing in a RelativeLayout made it layout correctly. Although it only worked for one of the screens, and it's pretty ugly, as well as throwing lint warnings. The second screen that is acting up filled the width properly, but not the height.

Comment: Amrut, you were entirely right. Apologies that it took me so long to mark your answer as correct. In essence though, you were correct. The root layout was the problem all along.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a custom activity as a container to other activities for some reason (In our case, we were recreating the look of our iOS app, and needed a custom menu to show up along the button side of the screen) the window manager seems to get a bit confused with what the actual height and width of the nested activities should be. A call to fillparent or matchparent ends up wrapping the content instead.

We ended up changing the behavior of several methods in our container activity class to make this work.